# find interval of convergence for power series of the following function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have found the power series for the following function, but I cannot figure out how to find it's interval of convergence due to the $x^2$ remaining.

The function is this (I'm so sorry I have not had the time to learn how to type the math stuff yet):

> $$f(x)= \frac{2}{1 - x^2}.$$

The power series is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2x^{2n}.$$

I tried the ratio test for finding the interval of convergence, but perhaps that is not a correct method?

Comment: What's wrong with applying the Ratio Test?

Comment: I end up with 2(lim n to infinity) x^2

Comment: Since $n$ doesn't appear in the argument of the limit, this is just $2 x^2$; also, the ratio should be $x^2$ (the $2$ coefficients of successive terms cancel).

Comment: where does the 2 cancel from? is the ratio is x^2, wouldn't it have to be square rooted to find that the radius of convergence is square root 1?

Comment: The ratio of terms is $\frac{2x^{2n+2}}{2x^n}$

Comment: Two successive terms in the series are $2x^{2n}$ and $2x^{2(n + 1)}$, and the ratio of these is $x^2$.

Comment: And yes, we're guaranteed convergence where the magnitude of the limiting ratio is $< 1$, in this case, this is where $x^2 < 1$.

Comment: As for typesetting mathematics here, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference is a fine resource.

Comment: so when x^2<1, shouldn't x<root 1?

Answer (score 1):

as above u found that 
$$x^2<1$$

$$|x|<1$$

$-1<x<1$,    Interval is (-1,1)